# Would questions about finding a statistic be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've been trying to find statistics about how many people the average person interacts with in a single day. I'm doing this as part of my research on the spread of infectious diseases.

Specifically, I wanted to ask "*What percentage of the total population does the average person interact with in a single day?*", but I wasn't sure if this was the right place to ask.

**Is it on-topic to ask questions about finding a statistic?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this would be regarded by many of our users as a question about "obtaining a particular data set", about which our [help/on-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Questions about obtaining particular datasets are off-topic (they are too specialized).